# django-widget-tweaks using field.name in render_field

Tags: django, django-widget-tweaks

I am using `django-widget-tweaks` and its `render_field`.  I have an odd situation and I wonder if there is a workaround or a different approach that I should use?

I am using `django` and `allauth` (I am not using the social auth part yet).  I have the default django user model and I have a "Profile" model that extends the user model.  That's all working.

This is a specialized "Membership App".  Only adults over 18 should be able to login.  Once logged in a person can create "member" one or more "member" records.  The logged in person is responsible for payng for memberships but might not be a member themselves; for example, a parent might log in and create member records for youth under 18 while not being a member themselves.

When creating a new member record I need to give the logged in person the opportunity to create a member record for themselves (if they don't already have one).  If they chose this option then the logged in person's "Profile" info should auto-fill the new member form.  To facilitate this I am capturing and serializing the logged in user's Profile info and am passing it to the CBV `MemberCreate` method.  This method renders the Member Create form using `django-widget-tweaks` and its `render_field` method, a la:

```
{% with field=newMemberForm.first_name %}
    {% render_field field class="form-control form-control-sm" %}
{% endwith %}
```

I want to create a `data-loggedindata=` attribute that uses the `field.name` value as the "member name" of the logged in person's profile.  SOmething like:

```
{% with field=newMemberForm.first_name %}
    {% render_field field class="form-control form-control-sm" data-loggedindata=LoggedInProfile.{{field.name}} %}
{% endwith %}
```

But `django-widget-tweaks` doesn't seem to understand that and I am not wise enough in the world of django to know a workaround.

I can hear someone typing: "but you know the field name from the `{% with ... %}` construct".  Yes, that is true but the Member form has a lot of fields so I wrapped the `render_field` part in a small html file that I `include`.  So the reall segment above might look like:

```
{% with field=profileForm.first_name %}
    <div class="form-group col col-3">
        {% include "Members/template_includes/field_render.html" %}
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

And the included file has the `render_field` in it.  Inside that included html file I have no idea of the name of the field.

ideas?

**Edit**

I have tried Pankaj's suggestion below but

```
{% render_field field|attr:"data-loggedindata=LoggedInProfile.{{field.name}}" %}
```

does not appear to interpolate the object `LoggedInProfile` or the `{{field.name}}` value.  What I get is the un-interpolated string "LoggedInProfile.{{field.name}}".

I have tried:

```
{% render_field field|attr:"data-loggedindata:getattr(LoggedInProfile, field.name" %}
```

but that is not interpolated either.  Is there a way in a Django template and/or widget-tweaks to programatically get the value of an object attribute?

**Edit 2**

I decided to go another way.  I am still using `widget-tweaks` but I am not trying to use `render_field` in this way anymore.  I am serializing the data that would be placed in the `data-` elements and placing the JSON version in a hidden form field.  I am letting javascript deal with it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add attribute in field with `django-widget-tweaks` you can simply use `attr` for that, in your case it would be like -

```
{% with field=newMemberForm.first_name %}
    {% render_field field|add_class:"form-control form-control-sm"|attr:"data-loggedindata=LoggedInProfile.{{field.name}}" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Still have any doubts let me know