# Django widget tweaks and variable attributes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, htmx, django-widget-tweaks

Trying to include variables as attributes and values into a form field in a Django app template via a partial/component.

There is [a somewhat related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53027477/9398743) but to my understanding it covers one side of the problem I am facing with django-widget-tweaks and custom tags.

In my case I not only want to assign a dynamic value to a predefined attribute (which I can do with extra template tags as described for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23783666/9398743)) but to first dynamically create an attribute and assign a value to it for the purpose of htmx requests such as `hx-get` or `hx-post`.

Including partials behaves as expected if I specify the type of htmx request directly in `render_field` and pass the value (in this case URL) via `include` as well as when I add the attribute and hard code its value using `|attr:` like so:

`{% include "partials/input-text.html" with field=form.email|attr:"hx-post:/search/" %}`

I have tried to apply `append_attr` the newly created attribute but I'm seeing `AttributeError: 'SafeString' object has no attribute 'as_widget'` and also getting a sensation that I'm missing the point.

Ideally I'm seeking to be able to pass attribute&value as variables (could be via custom template tags), along the lines of `{% include "partials/input-text.html" with field|attr:"{{hxaction}}:{{hxurl}}" %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I've read about doing complicated template stuff like this, there's always people saying it's not what django templates are made for.. So you should try and have **as much** logic as you can in the backend and **not** in the template..

and to do this I'd say you should extend the Form.py

##### Basic Attributes (forms.py)

```py
class TheForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = The
        fields = (
            'email',
            )

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(TheForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'hx-post':'/search/'}
```

##### More Dynamic Attributes (forms.py)

- Passing extra kwargs to form

```py
class TheForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = The
        fields = (
            'email',
            )

    # helper
    def ValOrDefault(self, key, default_value):
        if self.extra and key in self.extra:
            return self.extra[key]
        return default_value

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra =  kwargs['extra'] if 'extra' in kwargs else None
        super(TheForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'hx-post': ValOrDefault('email_hx-post', '/search/'),
        };
```

##### More Dynamic Attributes (view.py)

```py
extraDict = {
    'email_hx-post': '/sendmail/{0}'.format(obj.email),
    # more attributes, different fields
}

form = TheForm(extra=extraDict)
```

Now there's definitely smarter ways you could do the dynamic.. That's just generally what I'd do with my current understanding, probably had some more helper functions